# MySQL - Fetching users who sent the most recent messages

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a messages table as follows:

[image: group_messages table]

Basically what I want is, I want to fetch `n` users who sent the most recent messages to a group. So it has to be grouped by `from_user_id` and sorted by `id` in descending order. I have the following query:

```
SELECT `users`.`id` AS `user_id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`image` 
FROM `group_messages`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `group_messages`.`from_user_id`
WHERE `group_messages`.`to_group_id` = 31
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `group_messages`.`id` DESC;
```

The problem with this is, when I group by `user.id`, the row with the smallest `id` field is taken into account. Therefor what I get is not in the order which `id` is descending.

So is there a way to group by, taking the greatest `id` into account ? Or should I approach it another way ?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**: I think I got it.

```
SELECT `x`.`id`, `users`.`id` AS `user_id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`image` 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `group_messages` ORDER BY `group_messages`.`id` DESC) `x`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `x`.`from_user_id`
WHERE `x`.`to_group_id` = 31
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `x`.`id` DESC;
```

Just had to make a select from an already ordered list.

Comment: You should approach it in another way.  A typical way is to use aggregation to get the most recent message id and then join in the rest of the fields.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you enlight me ?

Answer (score 0):

Using order by inside subquery is not a very efficient way. Try this:

```
users table
| uid | name | ---------- |

messages table
|id | from_uid | to_group_id | ----------- |

    SELECT u.* FROM users as u JOIN (
    SELECT g1.*
    FROM messages g1 LEFT JOIN messages g2
    ON g1.from_uid = g2.from_uid AND g1.to_groupid = g2.to_groupid 
      AND g1.id<g2.id
    WHERE g2.id is NULL) as lastmessage
    ON lastmessage.from_uid = u.uid
    WHERE lastmessage.to_groupid = 1
    ORDER BY lastmessage.id DESC;
```

Its not good to have order by in subqueries because they will make the queries slow and in your case u were running it on  the whole table .

Check this out [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group).

Comment: Error? or its not giving the expected output?

Comment: It gives syntax error. Tried to fix the error but didn't seem to work.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43a0e2/1 Fiddle for the above schema. I think this should work now. :D